# continuous wavelet transfrom of a signal

Tags: scipy, wavelet-transform

I want to carry out continuous wavelet transform of a signal. I tried to write a script but the script give output of very low resolution scalogram. So I need a high resolution output by changing some scales. The signal data and the script is attached below.

I tried the script

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import obspy
w=np.loadtxt('signal')
t = np.arange(0,len(w))

fmin = 1  # Hz
fmax = 50  # Hz
df = 1./(t[-1]-t[0]) 
print(df)
fmin_samples = int(fmin/df)
fmax_samples = int(fmax/df)
extent = np.arange(1,10)

scalogram = signal.cwt(w, signal.morlet,extent)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
ax[0].plot(t, w)
ax[0].set(ylabel='amplitude')
ax[1].imshow(np.abs(scalogram), origin='lower')
ax[1].axis('tight')
ax[1].set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='frequency (Hz)')
plt.show()
```

signal data

```
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0001
   -0.0001
   -0.0001
   -0.0001
   -0.0001
   -0.0001
   -0.0001
   -0.0001
   -0.0001
   -0.0001
   -0.0001
   -0.0001
   -0.0001
   -0.0001
   -0.0001
   -0.0001
   -0.0002
   -0.0002
   -0.0002
   -0.0002
   -0.0002
   -0.0002
   -0.0002
   -0.0002
   -0.0002
   -0.0003
   -0.0003
   -0.0003
   -0.0003
   -0.0003
   -0.0004
   -0.0004
   -0.0004
   -0.0004
   -0.0005
   -0.0005
   -0.0006
   -0.0006
   -0.0007
   -0.0007
   -0.0008
   -0.0009
   -0.0009
   -0.0010
   -0.0011
   -0.0013
   -0.0014
   -0.0015
   -0.0017
   -0.0019
   -0.0022
   -0.0025
   -0.0028
   -0.0032
   -0.0037
   -0.0043
   -0.0051
   -0.0060
   -0.0072
   -0.0087
   -0.0108
   -0.0136
   -0.0178
   -0.0241
   -0.0338
   -0.0493
   -0.0724
   -0.1014
   -0.1231
   -0.1059
   -0.0038
    0.2143
    0.5147
    0.7698
    0.8049
    0.5211
   -0.0000
   -0.5212
   -0.8050
   -0.7698
   -0.5148
   -0.2144
    0.0038
    0.1059
    0.1231
    0.1013
    0.0725
    0.0492
    0.0340
    0.0240
    0.0174
    0.0136
    0.0106
    0.0086
    0.0070
    0.0059
    0.0049
    0.0042
    0.0036
    0.0031
    0.0026
    0.0023
    0.0020
    0.0018
    0.0015
    0.0014
    0.0012
    0.0010
    0.0009
    0.0008
    0.0007
    0.0006
    0.0005
    0.0004
    0.0003
    0.0003
    0.0002
    0.0001
    0.0000
   -0.0000
   -0.0001
   -0.0002
   -0.0003
   -0.0004
   -0.0005
   -0.0006
   -0.0007
   -0.0008
   -0.0010
   -0.0011
   -0.0013
   -0.0015
   -0.0018
   -0.0020
   -0.0024
   -0.0028
   -0.0034
   -0.0040
   -0.0049
   -0.0060
   -0.0074
   -0.0094
   -0.0123
   -0.0167
   -0.0235
   -0.0344
   -0.0506
   -0.0709
   -0.0861
   -0.0740
   -0.0026
    0.1501
    0.3604
    0.5389
    0.5635
    0.3649
    0.0001
   -0.3648
   -0.5634
   -0.5388
   -0.3603
   -0.1500
    0.0027
    0.0742
    0.0862
    0.0710
    0.0508
    0.0345
    0.0239
    0.0169
    0.0123
    0.0096
    0.0075
    0.0062
    0.0050
    0.0042
    0.0035
    0.0030
    0.0026
    0.0023
    0.0020
    0.0017
    0.0015
    0.0014
    0.0012
    0.0011
    0.0010
    0.0009
    0.0008
    0.0007
    0.0007
    0.0006
    0.0006
    0.0005
    0.0005
    0.0004
    0.0004
    0.0004
    0.0003
    0.0003
    0.0003
    0.0003
    0.0003
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
```

Comment: Please do **not** vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Using a library named PyWavelets (documentation [here](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) you can do it in a straightforward way

```
import pywt
import pylab
[phi, psi, x] = pywt.Wavelet('db2').wavefun(level=4)
pylab.plot(x, psi)
pylab.show()
```

Comment: can you modify it for my input data